# how to shutdown springboot immediately while configuration is wrong?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a question while developing my own components depending on autoconfiguration, and there are required critical parameters.

So I have a checking method in my component which annotated with `@PostConstruct`

If the configuration was wrong, I want this method to print the error log and shutdown application immediately just like if I set something wrong in springboot's basic configuration.

But the fact is, while using `SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext)`to shut down the application ,the application will remain running and stuck in somewhere and will not shut down.

the exception strack trace is shown below:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-07-15 17:37:28.623 [app:application-center,traceId:,spanId:,parentId:] [main] ERROR | SpringApplication.java:837 | o.s.boot.SpringApplication | Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@320494b6 has been closed already
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.assertBeanFactoryActive(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.eagerlyInitialize(RefreshScope.java:127)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.start(RefreshScope.java:118)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.onApplicationEvent(RefreshScope.java:112)
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope.onApplicationEvent(RefreshScope.java:66)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:898)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:554)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.myapp.applicationcenter.Application.main(Application.java:24)
```

Comment: Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.2 for a fix. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27049

Answer (score 1):

Well,after injection

```
    @Resource
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext
```

using `((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).close()` in a try catch block, shutting down the application after catching exceptions will solve the problem.

Are there more graceful ways to do so?

Comment: Throwing an exception instead of manually stopping yourself (which you generally shouldn't be doing anyway).